# Why is the module blacklisted?

Tags: drivers, kernel, blacklist

The module `intel-mid_wdt` is blacklisted. I searched (here, google, launchpad) for the reason why it is blacklisted but I could not find any reason. Is there a general list where I can get an explanation why a certain module is blacklisted by default?

Comment: Why do you think it is blacklisted? it is not blacklisted in Ubuntu.

Comment: `# grep intel-mid_wdt /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_linux_4.4.0-59-generic.conf` `blacklist intel-mid_wdt`

Comment: All watchdog drivers are disabled unless a watchdog daemon is installed.

Comment: And I do not have this line in my file.

Comment: `# Autogenerated watchdog blacklist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not exist any list with all modules. Some modules are just blacklisted because they make trouble on certain hardware. Sometimes it is easy to get the reasons by googling. However most of the time it is almost impossible.